# Vuejs get dynamic form all values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have select and input component with made by buefy. Everything is ok till I realize how can I get the data.

I'm sort of new on vuejs. So I will be glad if you help me out.

Maybe I can do with Javascript but how?

I'm getting dynamic form from backend

Here is my codes;

Input.vue

```
<template>
  <b-field :label="fieldLabel">
    <b-input
      :name="inputName"
      :type="inputType"
      :maxlength="inputType == 'textarea' ? 200 : null"
    ></b-input>
  </b-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: {
    inputType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "text",
    },
    inputName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    fieldLabel: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container is-max-desktop wrapper">
   
            <div v-for="element in offer" :key="element.id">
              <Input
                v-model="element.fieldValue"
                :fieldLabel="element.fieldLabel"
                :inputType="element.fieldType"
                :inputName="element.fieldName"
                v-if="element.fieldType != 'select'"
                class="mb-3"
              />
              <Select
                v-model="element.fieldValue"
                :fieldLabel="element.fieldLabel"
                :options="element.infoRequestFormOptions"
                :selectName="element.fieldName"
                v-if="element.fieldType == 'select'"
                class="mb-3"
              />
            </div>
            <b-button type="is-danger" @click="getOffer()">GET</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Select from "../components/Select.vue";
import Input from "../components/Input.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      offer: [],
    };
  },
  components: {
    Select,
    Input,
  },
  methods: {
    getOfferForm() {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `/GETDYNAMICFORM`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          this.offer = response.data;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$buefy.toast.open({
            duration: 3000,
            message: "oops",
            position: "is-bottom",
            type: "is-danger",
          });
        });
    },
    getOffer() {
      console.log(this.offer);
      
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getOfferForm();
  },
};
</script>
```

Example Dynamic Form Response like;

> [ { "id": 58, "fieldLabel": "Name Surname", "providerLabel": "Name
> Surname", "fieldName": "nmsrnm", "fieldType": "text", "fieldValue":
> null, }, { "id": 60, "fieldLabel": "E-mail", "providerLabel":
> "E-mail", "fieldName": "e_mail_60", "fieldType": "email",
> "fieldValue": null, }, { "id": 2, "fieldLabel": "Budget",
> "providerLabel": "Budget", "fieldName": "bdget", "fieldType":
> "select", "fieldValue": "", "infoRequestFormOptions": [ { "id": 1,
> "orderNum": 0, "optionValue": 0, "optionText": "Select", "minValue":
> null, "maxValue": null }, { "id": 2, "orderNum": 1, "optionValue": 1,
> "optionText": "10-30", "minValue": 10, "maxValue": 30 } ] } ]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.